# Model plotted not clear with plot_model

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

When `tensorflow` version `2.3.0` is used it gives unclear output model, how to resolve it?

```
import tensorflow as tf

base_model = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB7(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)  # or weig
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(base_model, to_file="image1.png", dpi=120)
```

It looks like the following

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is, that the model you try to output as image is a **HUGE** one. So `dpi=120` is barely enough in PNG format. In order to get a clearer image save it as a PDF. Then you can easily transform to image if you wish.

Using the follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

base_model = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB7(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)  # or weig
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(base_model, to_file="image1.pdf", dpi=120)
```

Gave me the following (when I just printed the screen on a specific block):

[image]